# errorreading values from a binary file c++

Tags: c++, io, binary

// The array values are set after few calculations

```
 long int a1[356];
 long int b2[356];
 long int c3[356];
```

// writin to binary file

```
ofstream output("h.h",ios::binary|ios::out|ios::app);

output.write((char*)a1,356*4);
output.write((char*)b2,356*4);
output.write((char*)c3,356*4);
```

// read as

```
long int *x=new long int[1424];
ifstream in("h.h",ios::binary|ios::in);

in.read((char*)x,1424);

vector<long int> e1;
vector<long int> e2;
vector<long int> e3;

for(int y=;y<=1424;y=y+4)
{
 // e1.push_back((int)x[i]);

}
```

I am using the above method to read the integers written to the binary by I am not able to retrieve the values as stored . . can someone point where is the problem ?

Thanks!

Comment: Remember that `long int` may actually have different size than 4. Use `sizeof(long int)`.

Comment: U are using ios::app which appends data, are you sure you are not reading older data?

Comment: I am sure about why I wanted to ios::app.

Comment: I used it only after checking the size - @ Joachim

Answer (score 1):

With

```
long int *x=new long int[1424];
```

You declare a pointer pointing to an array of 1424 `long int`. But with the reading

```
in.read((char*)x,1424);
```

You are reading 1424 *bytes*.

And in the loop you loop over the array, but add 4 to the index, so only every four element of `x` is pushed back.

---

You should first think about that may `long` is *eight* bytes on 64-bit machines. You also don't really need to allocate the array dynamically. And the array should contain 356 entries, just like when you wrote it to the file. You can then read `sizeof(x)` bytes in the call to read. And finally in the loop, you loop from 0 to `sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])`:

```
long int x[356];
ifstream in("h.h",ios::binary|ios::in);

in.read((char*) x, sizeof(x));

for(int y = 0; y < (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0])); y++)
{
}
```

---

<strike>If you want to read the contents as `long int` into a `std::vector`, there are actually a "simpler" way, using iterators and standard C++ algorithms:</strike>

```
std::vector<long int> e1;

std::ifstream in("h.h", std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);

std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<long int>(in),
            356,
            std::back_inserter(e1));
```

The above statements declares a vector, opens a file, and copies 356 `long int` entries from the file into the vector `e1`.

For references, see [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator), [`std::back_inserter`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter), and of course [`std::copy_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy_n).

---

The above C++ solution wasn't working, so I've experimented with another:

```
std::vector<long> v(356);

std::ifstream in("h.h", std::ios::binary);

std::for_each(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [&in](long& v) {
    in.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&v), sizeof(v));
});
```

The above solution have been tested with [this program](http://pastebin.com/77rHLAY2), and it works for me.

What the above statements to, is create a vector containing 356 `long` entries, opens the file, and reads into the vector one entry at a time.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that before but couldn't sort out a way to consider other three bytes as well. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @user2090617 I've updated my answer a couple of times, once with a more "naive" C-ish solution, and once with a more idiomatic pure C++ solution.

Comment: I tried using copy_n  , the test returned garbage values @ Joachim

Comment: @user2090617 Are you sure you write correct data? Do you write and read the file on the same computer?

Comment: Yes, I am sure about them !

Comment: @user2090617 And you are not using a 64-bit system (remember that most moderately systems are)?

Comment: I am using a 64 bit system, the size of long int is 4 bytes on my machine. I checked the size.

Comment: @user2090617 Actually, using 64-bit systems increases the change of `long` to be just 64 bits. But if you checked with e.g. `sizeof(long)` then it probably means you are on Windows and using Visual C++. Please hold a little while, while I make some simple tests.

Comment: @user2090617 I've made a small test program to test vector input and output. Please see the bottom of my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot Joachim Pileborg . . Your answer was very useful.